# Can stock market capital losses be used to offset income tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, capital-gains-tax

Suppose a U.S citizen made massive losses in the stock market. He draws a high salary from his day job which makes him liable to high income tax. His massive losses happens to exceed his entire year's salary income. Can he offset his stock market losses against his income tax so that he pays zero tax for the financial year?

Comment: You have to offset capital gains first if you have any, then up to $3,000 / yr normal income and roll the rest forward.

Answer (score 4):

If one is getting more than $3,000/year in income, the answer is, no, the capital losses won't zero out one's tax liability.

Basically, one can use capital losses to offset capital gains (detail: there's an order in which long/short term losses offset long/short term gains that I'm ignoring in the interest of clarity) up to the amount of the gain.  If there's still capital losses, then one can take up to $3,000 each year as an offset against regular income.  If there is still a capital loss, one can carry it forward as a capital loss for the next year.  The carry-forward is effectively lending money for a year or more and no interest to the federal government.

Because of this, it's a common trick to harvest tax losses at the end of the year to offset capital gains (see https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Tax_loss_harvesting for a more involved discussion).